ln: failed to create symbolic link. Operation not permitted
I have this problem when I put this: ln -s ../../data/*EOF .
ln: failed to create symbolic link './S1A_OPER_AUX_POEORB_OPOD_20210510T121540_V20210419T225942_20210421T005942.EOF': Operation not permitted

I have also tried to do it with sudo ln -s ../../data/*EOF .
Does anyone know what to do?

Your ln command shows only the first operation, that is the real path.  where will the link go?

Does this answer your question? How to create a soft or symbolic link?

That asterisk in the real path parameter of the link command could be ambiguous.  Replace it with the one and only name it would resolve to.  Also, don't forget the second parameter of a link command for a symbolic link

You can use ln with the target as the only parameter, the link will be created in the current directory then.

As @mook765 said, you don't have to supply that second parameter but, in this specific case, the resulting link would be something like like S1A_OPER_AUX_POEORB_OPOD_20210510T121540_V20210419T225942_20210421T005942.EOF.
